# Binding slider to adapt to audio position without causing performance degradation

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have an mp3 player app made with **python & kivy** and I want to create a slider that its value adapts to the song position.

I already have some solutions but the problem with all of them is that they make the audio playback unpleasant and glitchy.

Currently I use **Clock** to run a function every one second but as I mentioned before it makes the audio very laggy and impossible to listen to.

My Code:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.path = "C:/Users/Family/Downloads/10_poker_face.mp3"
        self.song = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
#:import Clock kivy.clock.Clock
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: app.path
        font_size: 32
    Slider:
        id: song_slider
        min: 0
        max: app.song.length
        on_value: app.song.seek(self.value)
    Button:
        text: "Play"
        font_size: 32
        on_release:
            Clock.schedule_interval(app.update_slider, 1)
            app.song.play()
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    def update_slider(self, dt):
        self.kv.ids.song_slider.value = self.song.get_pos()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

I even tried a threading alternative but this was even worse than the clock method:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"
from threading import Thread
from time import time
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.path = "C:/Users/Family/Downloads/10_poker_face.mp3"
        self.song = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
        self.start_time = None
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Label:
        text: app.path
        font_size: 32
    Slider:
        id: song_slider
        min: 0
        max: app.song.length
        on_value: app.song.seek(self.value)
    Button:
        text: "Play"
        font_size: 32
        on_release: app.start_song()
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    def start_song(self):
        self.start_time = time()
        Thread(target=self.update_slider, daemon=True).start()
        self.song.play()

    def update_slider(self):
        while True:
            now = time()
            if now - self.start_time >= 1:
                self.start_time = now
                self.kv.ids.song_slider.value = self.song.get_pos()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

How can I bind the slider to adapt to the audio position of the song without causing performance problems?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer such a solution, it works independently of the `KIVY_AUDIO` argument.

```py
import os
os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.app import App

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    padding: 10
    orientation: 'vertical'
    
    Label:
        text: app.path
        halign: 'center'
        font_size: sp(32)
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: self.texture_size[1]

    Slider:
        id: song_slider
        min: 0
        max: 100
        
    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Play'
        font_size: sp(32)
        on_release: app.start_song()
'''


class MainApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.path = 'music.mp3'

        self.song = SoundLoader.load(self.path)
        self.clock_event = None
        self.kv = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    def start_song(self):
        if self.song.state == 'stop':
            self.song.play()
            self.clock_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_slider, self.song.length / 60)
            self.kv.ids.btn.text = 'Stop'
        else:
            self.clock_event.cancel()
            self.song.stop()
            self.kv.ids.song_slider.value = 0
            self.kv.ids.btn.text = 'Play'

    def update_slider(self, *args):
        if self.kv.ids.song_slider.value < 100:
            self.kv.ids.song_slider.value += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```